Como resolver dependência cíclica em Go com princípios SOLID?
Estou trabalhando em um projeto em Go onde tenho dois domínios, Ingredient e Recipe. Cada um deles está em seu próprio pacote (ingredientdomain e recipedomain). Aqui estão as definições básicas:
Domain -> ingredientdomain -> ingredientdomain.go
package ingredientdomain

type IngredientDomain struct {
    ...
    Recipes []recipedomain.RecipeDomainInterface
    ...
}

Domain -> recipedomain -> recipedomain.go
package recipedomain

type RecipeDomain struct {
    ...
    Ingredients []ingredientdomain.IngredientDomainInterface
    ...
}

IngredientDomain tem uma lista de RecipeDomainInterface e vice-versa, o que está causando uma dependência cíclica.
Estou tentando seguir os princípios SOLID, então gostaria de manter a lógica de negócios (domínios) separada da persistência de dados (entidades). No entanto, estou tendo dificuldade em resolver essa dependência cíclica sem violar esses princípios.
Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema de uma maneira que esteja alinhada com os princípios SOLID?

Esta pergunta já foi postada. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, qualquer melhoria ou alteração deve ser feita naquela, clicanado em "editar" logo abaixo das tags).
